# Can my Canon 600EX II-RT on-camera flash trigger a 430EX-II off-camera flash, or do I need tranceiver(s) as well?

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, wedding

I am a beginning wedding photographer using off camera flash for the first time during a wedding reception.  It will be outdoors in a big white tent.  I plan to mount my Canon 600EX II-RT on-camera to use for candids, photos of guests, etc. and have my Canon 430EX-II on a stand by the dance floor for toasts, first dance, etc.

My question is, with this setup do I need a pocketwizard or some sort of transceiver attached to the 430EX-II, or if it is set up as a slave will it fire with the 600EX II-RT alone?  If I do need a transceiver, do I need one for the 600 as well?

Apologies for the novice question, as this is my first time using a two-speedlite setup.

Comment: Hi Hannah, welcome to Photo-SE. I took the liberty of editing the title to be descriptive of your question. I hope I got it right, but if I didn't, please feel free to edit it to be more accurate to your intent. =)

Comment: If the 430 is a also RT then no problem. If not you can likely use the 600 as  a line-of-sight controller. Personally I would use the smaller flash on the camera anyway.

Comment: The 430EX II is not an RT flash. The 430EX III-RT is the first "430 series" flash with RT capability.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about this, depending on whether you need the advantages of *radio* or whether you can make do with *optical* wireless communication.

If radio, you need an RT compatible radio receiver to attach to the hot foot of the 430EX II. The 600EX II-RT has a built in RT radio that would communicate with the receiver. The most obvious candidate would be the [Yongnuo YNE3-RX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TGUR6TS).

You can also use Canon's older wireless optical control system. Set the 600EX II-RT into optical Master mode and use the 430EX II as a "smart" optical slave.

The advantages of radio versus optical wireless control are:

- Radio tends to have a greater range
- Doesn't require line-of-sight
- Can operate in very bright environments such as direct sunlight (that gives the optical system a tough time)
- Has the ability for more than one set of the same type to be used in proximity to one another without interfering with each other.

Comment: Optical should work OK in a tent (radio would be better). I would be more concerned with using off camera flash for the first time at a wedding.